# Using commas to connect independent clauses

Tags: semicolons, oxford-comma

I know that it is correct to connect independent clauses using a comma and a coordinating conjunction (for, and, nor, but, or, yet, so) as in "He rides a bike, and she drives a car."

But is it correct to connect 3 independent clauses using only 1 conjunction?

"He rides a bike, she drives a car, and I just walk."

Comment: Why do you think it isn't acceptable?  How do you think it should be written, and why?

Comment: Not exactly but related, the [comma splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct because the comma implies the conjunction. You actually don't even need the last comma at all, though sometimes it helps to clarify (most common example: let's eat, grandma vs let's eat grandma).

For your example:

He rides a bike, she drives a car, and I just walk.

would be expanded as

He rides a bike and she drives a car and I just walk.

(*Note that with the use of the word 'just', 'but' would probably be a better conjunction:* 'He rides a bike, she drives a car, *but* I just walk).

Examples for the other conjunctions:

He neither rides a bike, drives a car, nor walks. ('nor' would take place of the comma).

He wants to ride a bike, drive a car, or walk.

Has he ridden a bike, driven a car or walked yet?